# WooCommerce Tax - Nothing is showing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I cannot make the woocommerce taxes (VAT) work! I have made all the settings like I see from tutorials but the VAT is not calculating or appearing anywhere!

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJqS3.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BwOt.png

Answer (score 2):

I found a bug with Variable Products and tax calcuations.

Basically, you have to set the Parent Products Tax Status to "Taxable" before creating the variations.  The value is copied at the time the variation is created.

The bug is that even if you change the Parent Products Tax Status to "Taxable", it does not cascade to the child variations.

A simple bit of SQL will make all Products and Variations taxable.

```
update wp_postmeta set meta_value = 'taxable' WHERE meta_key = '_tax_status'
```